# browse button in input box to find file Excel2007 Vba

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I need the browse button in input box to find file  -   VB A - EXCEL Macro][1]

need to find the folder path via browse button instead of typing in input box
is it possible?

|-------------------|

|-------------------| Browse
 by clicking a cell it should ask for file browse.
should not be edited manually. i mean , i want to lock the particular cell locked. and only able to edit via macro.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to find a file. Modify the filter if you need to. the variable `fldr` will have your data. Then you can set your textbox to that value.

```
Sub File_Picker()
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Text", "*.txt", 1
        .InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then GoTo 1
        fldr = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
End Sub
```

or:

```
Sub Folder_Picker()
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then GoTo 1
        fldr = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
End Sub
```

I have more helpful pieces of code like this at [My GitHub](https://github.com/MakeCents/Excel_VBA/tree/master/Tools)

Comment: need to find the folder path via browse button insted of typing in inputbox is it possible?

Comment: [Folder_Picker](https://github.com/MakeCents/Excel_VBA/blob/master/Tools/Tools_Dialog_Boxes.bas) will be the one you want then?

Comment: @MakeCents, the "1" label for "GoTo 1" is missing from your answer. I had to go to your GitHub to realize it goes on the "End With" line.

Answer (score 4):

Alternately:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim strFilePath As String

    strFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If strFilePath = "False" Then Exit Sub  'Pressed cancel

    MsgBox strFilePath

End Sub
```