# Folder Picker for MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working on a Mail Merge Export Function. I would like to add a "Select Folder" Dialog box.

I found this in my googling which is similar ([browse button in input box to find file Excel2007 Vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358964/browse-button-in-input-box-to-find-file-excel2007-vba) ) but I want to choose a folder, not a file. The file name and type is auto generated through the export.

```
Sub Export_Docs()
    'Used to set criteria for moving through the document by section.
    Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowseSection

    'A mailmerge document ends with a section break next page.
    'Subtracting one from the section count stop error message.
    For i = 1 To ((ActiveDocument.Sections.Count) - 1)

      'Select and copy the section text to the clipboard
      ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Section").Range.Copy

      'Create a new document to paste text from clipboard.
      Documents.Add
      'To save your document with the original formatting'
      Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

      'Removes the break that is copied at the end of the section, if any.
      Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
      Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
      'Sets Save Location and Document Name Parameters'

      ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\tveinot\Documents\Asset Management\Buildings\"
      MyString = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(6, 3).Range.Text
      Filename = Left(MyString, 13)
      DocNum = DocNum + 1
      ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=Filename & ".doc"
      ActiveDocument.Close
      'Move the selection to the next section in the document
      Application.Browser.Next
    Next i
    ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

Comment: I have gotten Closer with this using Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).ButtonName = "Select Path" I found on a VB Tutorial but I cannot seem to pass the variable to the ChangeDirectory everything saves in C:\.

Answer (score 3):

First [Google match](https://www.google.sk/search?q=select+directory+vba) gave me [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/294728-browse-folder-visual-basic-applications.html):

```
Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Tested: works fine. In the above code you can also see how they set initial path.

Comment: Thank you! It took me a bit to insert it into my code block but once I did it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.. If the answer helped, please do not forget to mark it so the question will no longer appear open (unanswered).